# Android : Is it possible to change background color of ImageView with setColorFilter?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, imageview, android-imageview

For some reasons, I have problems with changing the background color of an ImageView when using setBackgrouncolor(). What I want is to change the backgroundcolor of my ImageView to Color.TRANSPARENT. Is there another way than :

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
iv.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

to change the background color to transparent of my imageView.

May it be done for example with setColorFilter() ? Something like: (with what convenient mode?)

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
iv.setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Or any other solution ?

Thanks !

MY ANSWER:

I didn't see that one of the images I placed in my superimposition of ImageViews had a white background instead of a transparent background... So there were ,no bug. My mistake!

Answer (score 0):

Your first code block (below) works just fine. It's even unnecessary in most cases since the default background color of an ImageView is transparent.

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
iv.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

I tested this by creating an ImageView in an otherwise blank activity layout and giving it a background color of red. I then added your code to the onCreate() method of the activity and when I ran it, the background color became transparent as the layout background color of white showed through. You can test this yourself using the following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myImageView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#FF0000" />

</FrameLayout>
```

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do with a transparent background, but if you are loading a JPG image into the ImageView, transparency will not be supported unless you modify the canvas on which it is displayed. If you want to support transparency within your image, you'll need to use a format such as SVG or PNG.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Source [Android Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable#setColorFilter(int,%20android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode))

```
public void setColorFilter (int color,PorterDuff.Mode mode)
```

This method was deprecated in API level 29.use this instead:

```
setColorFilter(android.graphics.ColorFilter)
```

with an instance of BlendModeColorFilter

example:

```
iv.setColorFilter(new BlendModeColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.White), BlendMode.SRC_IN));
```

if its transparency you want:

```
imageView.setAlpha(0.5f);
```